# dynamically position views obtained from AbsoluteLayout xml

Tags: android, coordinates

I am placing my views on AbsoluteLayout (although deprecated) so I can get the specific X,Y coordinates  when I create the views dynamically from java. I am doing this to  use animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/france_italy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="258dp"

            android:src="@drawable/france_italy"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="-145dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/production_chart_wing"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:src="@drawable/production_chart_wing"
            android:layout_x="54dp"
            android:layout_y="2dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"

            android:src="@drawable/lx4p01"
            android:layout_x="111dp"
            android:layout_y="163dp"/>

   </AbsoluteLayout>
```

But although I set the X, Y coordinates, they are not as per the AbsoluteLayout layout (layout_x /layout_y etc) and the size of the views also shrinks. I am using a Navigation drawer with TabLayout and view pager if that matters. I would like to know how can I use the information from Absolute Layout to create views dynamically ?

```
public class ProductionChart extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        final ImageView france_italy = new ImageView(getActivity());
        france_italy.setId(R.id.france_italy);
        france_italy.setImageResource(R.drawable.france_italy);

        france_italy.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        final ImageView production_chart_wing = new ImageView(getActivity());
        production_chart_wing.setId(R.id.production_chart_wing);
        production_chart_wing.setImageResource(R.drawable.production_chart_wing);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        params.leftMargin = 54;
        params.topMargin = 2;


        production_chart_wing.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));


        relativeLayout.addView(france_italy);
        relativeLayout.addView(production_chart_wing,params);

        return relativeLayout;


    }
}
```